# how to open a specific webpage on a smart magic mirror running on RPI3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, voice-recognition

how to open a specific webpage on a smart magic mirror running on RPI3 using voice?

I need to use my voice and "Smart mirror, please open Google webpage". the mirror should respond by opening and showing the Google webpage for me.

Comment: Selenium may help.

Comment: To recognise your voice input, start with [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) then use the built-in [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html) module to launch your browser.

Comment: is it possible to launch a specific website ? Also, do u have a link that shows how to do that?